# tf.test.is_gpu_available() returns False on GCP

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gpu

I am training a CNN on GCP's notebook using a Tesla V100. I've trained a simple yolo on my own custom data and it was pretty fast but not very accurate. So, I decided to write my own code from scratch to solve the specific aspects of the problem that I want to tackle.

I have tried to run my code on Google Colab prior to GCP, and it went well. Tensorflow detects the GPU and is able to use it whether it was a Tesla K80 or T4.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
tf.test.is_gpu_available()  #>>> True
```

My problem is that, this same function returns a **False** on GCP notebook, as if Tensorflow is unable to use the GPU it detected on GCP VM. I don't know of any command that forces Tensorflow to use the GPU over CPU, since it does that automatically.
I have already tried to install or uninstall and then install some versions of tensorflow, tensorflow-gpu and tf-nightly-gpu (1.13 and 2.0dev for instance) but it yielded nothing.

[output of nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilpab.png)

Comment: I've just tested the ```print(device_lib.list_local_devices())``` again to make sure and it seems that Tensorflow is unable to detect the GPU. Only the CPU is shown in output

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using GCP's [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/) instead?  They offer VMs that are pre-configured with Tensorflow and have all required GPU drivers installed.

Comment: I was already on AI Platform Notebooks, I managed somehow to solve the problem, though I am not sure how. I ended up deleting the VM and creating another instance  of VM on which I run a JupyterLab notebook. took me long enough to copy my data but at least I was able to continue my work.